# How to open Keyboard Automatically on input item focus?

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

how can we open android phone keyboard automatically when input item get focused. This is a hybrid app with Cordova

As preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" for android is not supported so is it possible that we can do it through JavaScript/JQuery Mobile API

Comment: When any input field is focus the keyboard should focus. This is not related to mobilefirst. Android is supposed to do this. I have never needed to add any specialized code to get the keyboard displayed when tapping any input field.

Comment: Thanks Idan, Keyboard opens when tapping on input item but I just  want  to know a way to open it automatically without tapping input field just using .focus on that item.

Comment: try $(element).trigger("tap") or $(element).trigger("click") .